# Split line into category and text

Tags: python, split

I have list that looks like this:

```
foo = ["neg * , This is a sentence","pos * , This is another sentence"]
```

I need to split the sentences in such a way that one value will become the category, `neg` or `pos`, and one the sentence. 
I tried:

```
for text in foo:
    text = text.split("*")
    for a,b in text:
        cat=a
        text=b
```

However I get a "too many values to unpack", anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is that your actual indentation?

Comment: Yes, is it incorrect?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: was the original indentation what you had or the one from Inbar's edit? I ask because Python uses indentation to replace braces.

Comment: There is no way he would get a "too many values to unpack" error if his indentation was screwed up. He would have gotten a Syntax Error, or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is your loop is horribly constructed (which is excusable, since you are obviously new to the whole thing)

Try this safer method (a list-comprehension):

```
>>> foo = ["neg * , This is a sentence","pos * , This is another sentence"]
>>> [p.split('*', 1) for p in foo]
[['neg ', ' , This is a sentence'], ['pos ', ' , This is another sentence']]
```

Now you have a list of `[CAT, TEXT]` items.

```
>>> l = [p.split('*', 1) for p in foo]
>>> for cat, text in l:
    print 'cat: %s, text: %s' % (cat, text)

cat: neg , text:  , This is a sentence
cat: pos , text:  , This is another sentence
```

Comment: Yes, this works like a charm, thank you @Inbar Rose and thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Are you using Python 2? Maybe change the print to be python3, if shifu is a beginner, he may not notice...Anyway,good solution. edit:Oh, it works for him, sorry, didn't see his message

Answer (score 1):

The line `for a,b in text:` isn't appropriate. A better choice is `a,b=text`. The former code operates on a list of pairs, the latter operates on a single pair.

Applying that advice, and removing redundancies:

```
foo = ["neg * , This is a sentence","pos * , This is another sentence"]
for text in foo:
    a,b = text.split("*")
    # Now do something with 'a' and 'b'
```

If you *really* want to re-use the `text` variable, this works:

```
for text in foo:
    a, text = text.split("*")
    # Now do something with 'a' and 'text'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the assignment part in the inner loop wrong. Here, try this

```
lines = ["neg * , This is a sentence","pos * , This is another sentence"]
for line in lines:
    category, sentence = line.split("*", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over strings in the second loop

```
for text in foo:
    text = text.split("*")
    a,b = text:
```

In that case, you assign a to the first element of text and b the second one.
Otherwise you're splitting the string into characters and you don't have the same number of variables as the number of characters

Answer (score 0):

```
textList = []
catList = []
for str in foo:
    (cat,text) = str.split('*')
    textList.append(text)
    catList.append(cat)
```

Then `textList` is a list of text strings and `catList` is a list of cat strings. Otherwise you won't be able to access all the different cats and texts.

Comment: This is slightly misleading, as it suggest that `foo` contains lists, where it instead contains strings. And also, your naming conventions are not according to [Python PEP8 naming conventions style](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)